# React and Redux: 401 Unauthorized Error POST API Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-redux, axios

//Postman[image] //React App[image][image]
For my react app, when dispatching apiPostRequest() I am getting 401 unauthorized error when it hits API POST Request Middleware even though the user is authenticated and token is stored in local storage. The confusing part is that my GET and DELETE api requests work just fine. So I cannot figure out why then is POST api returning 401 unauthorized error? It works fine in Postman. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
//Accept request action

export const acceptRequest = (requestId) => ({
  type   : ACCEPT_REQUEST,
  payload: requestId
});
```

```
// Accept request middleware

export const acceptRequestFlow = ({dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {
  next(action);

    if(action.type === ACCEPT_REQUEST){
      const acceptRequestId = action.payload
      console.log(acceptRequestId)
      const URL = `/api/userConnections/acceptRequest/${action.payload}`;
      dispatch(apiPostRequest(URL, setAuthorizationHeader(getState), acceptRequestId, ACCEPT_REQUEST_SUCCESS, ACCEPT_REQUEST_ERROR));
    }
};
```

```
//API POST, DELETE, GET request actions

export const apiPostRequest = (url, config, body, onSuccess, onError) => ({
  type: POST_API_REQUEST,
  meta: {url, config, body, onSuccess, onError}
});
export const apiDeleteRequest = (url, config, id, onSuccess, onError) => ({
  type: DELETE_API_REQUEST,
  meta: {url, config, id, onSuccess, onError}
});
export const apiGetRequest = (url, config, onSuccess, onError) => ({
  type: GET_API_REQUEST,
  meta: {url, config, onSuccess, onError}
});
```

```
//API POST, DELETE, GET request middleware

export const api = ({dispatch}) => next => action => {

  if(action.type === POST_API_REQUEST) {
    const {url, config, body, onSuccess, onError} = action.meta;

    axios.post(url, config)
      .then((data) => {dispatch({ type: onSuccess, payload: body})})
      .catch(error => dispatch({ type: onError, payload: error }))
  }

  if(action.type === GET_API_REQUEST) {
    const {url, config, onSuccess, onError } = action.meta;

    axios.get(url, config)
      .then((data) => {dispatch({ type: onSuccess, payload: data})})
      .catch(error => dispatch({ type: onError, payload: error }))
  }

  if(action.type === DELETE_API_REQUEST) {

    const {url, config, id, onSuccess, onError } = action.meta;
    axios.delete(url, config)
      .then((data) => { dispatch({ type: onSuccess, payload: id })})
      .catch(error => dispatch({ type: onError, payload: error }))
  }


return next(action)
};
```

```
//Setting Auth Header

export const setAuthorizationHeader = (getState) =>{

    const token = getState().auth.token; 
    const config = {
      headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  if(token){
    config.headers['Authorization'] = token;
  }
  return config;
};
```

Comment: Try console logging your config and check for the header information if all the fields are correct. Other thing which can be checked are the CORS configuration for the server and allowed request methods , but since the POST request works through postman, the issue is with the dispatch request itself.

Comment: Yeah I did console log it and I am getting the correct header information which is Content-Type: "application/json", x-authorization: "Bearer  <token>". Same config is passed to my delete and get api routes and they work fine. The issue is with the post api route.

Comment: Have you checked your CORS configuration for the server ?

Comment: If you were to temporally turn off the authentication. Does the POST still return the 401 unauthorized error? It feels like the bearer token may be a red herring.

Comment: Greg, so when I temporarily turn off the authentication it successfully works. Weird. What could this mean?

Comment: Please post your `GET` or `DELETE` request code as well. It will help to compare between working and non-working code. Might help to figure out problem faster.

Comment: Sunil, I just updated my post and added the delete and get api requests as well. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: If you say, that it works in Postman, then it would be logical to include request-response from Postman too. So that you/we can see the difference.

Comment: x00, I added the request-response from postman as well. Thank you

Comment: @tim_woods can you update screenshot i can see `Authorization` token in it and can you also share your backend code used for post

Comment: Chandan, are you talking about the screen shot of the request payload which shows the content-type and token?

Comment: Thank you all for your effort. Daniel Sindrestean's response was correct and the issue has now been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the post method incorrectly.

[image]

As you can see from the image taken from axios [doc](https://github.com/axios/axios), when making a post without specifying the parameter name, then the second parameter passed in is perceived as data.

So try: `axios.post(url, {}, config)`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
//Setting Auth Header

export const setAuthorizationHeader = (getState) =>{

    const token = getState().auth.token; 
    const config = {
      headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  if(token){
    // change 'x-authorization' to 'Authorization'
    config.headers['Authorization'] = token;
  }
  return config;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It did not work. I dont think it makes a difference if I name it "x-authorization" or "Authorization.

Comment: can you log the response headers and put them here?

Comment: Updated my question with an image of the response headers. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: what about the request headers (screenshot)?

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated it again with the request headers as well.

Comment: in the Accept Request Middleware, you are calling next(action) first and then you  are not returning anything!
update it to return next(action) in the bottom of the  middleware!

Comment: Tried that already but I am getting the same error.

Comment: can you post the log of action.meta in the action.type == POST_API_REQUEST of the api middleware?

Comment: The action.meta returns the correct config, body, header with token, etc. So its very confusing. Not understanding why I am getting the 401 error

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Daniel Sindrestean's response was correct and the issue has been resolved.